# bcp error while exporting data using management studio in sql 2005 express but not using DOS

Tags: sql, client, native, bcp

i am using sql server 2005 express edition . 
when i export data via bcp utility using dos prompt then there is no error , 
but when i created a stored procedure for the export process and use management studio express for exporting data then it gives the following error :

**SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file**

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the `bcp` utility using the DOS command line you are using the logged in persons credentials (usually your own), but when running as a stored procedure you are using the credentials of the SQL server process, which usually is configured to have much less permissions than ordinary users in order to provide safety against various attacks.

Check in the Services list of which user is used for the SQL server database engine and check if that user has enough read/write permissions to the directories and files involved.

Comment: thanks a lot sir, i checked out under Services in the control panel. in the service MSSQLSERVER, under its properties , on the LOG ON tab, i found that mssqlserver instance was logged on as AUTHORITY\NetworkService , so i changed it now to Local account. now after restarting the service, the bcp task is successfully completed . thanks a lot sir for your great help.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, but the answer is that I was being less than bright.

As the command was being run on a server, not my local machine, it was trying to write to a non-existent folder on the server. It was executing successfully against the root of C: but not against my share folder, C:\share. The problem for me was that I was looking for the file in the root of my C Drive, not the servers.

When I changed the path to \mymachinename\share, everything worked.

Comment: In my case, I forgot to provide a datafile argument :facepalm: